# How to handle upload File in Plone using plone.api create and NamedBlobFile

Tags: python, blob, plone, zope

Dears,

I have been create a script to read a txt and do a upload in Plone site (Plone 4.3.10).
The script is here:
[Script Python using plone.api to create File appear error WrongType when set a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38351633/script-python-using-plone-api-to-create-file-appear-error-wrongtype-when-set-a-f)

I use a tip described by MrTango:
[Save file to plone site using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29408529/save-file-to-plone-site-using-python/29410325#29410325)

My difficulty is attach the file into a new item created in begin of FOR, specifically in the following passage:

```
    file_obj.file = NamedBlobFile(
        data=open(pdf_path, 'r').read(),
        contentType='application/pdf',
        filename=unicode(file_obj.id, 'utf-8'),
    )
```

The parameter "data", receave file PDF from filesystem, but, don't set up file in a new object, newly created.

Thank You for your attention!

**[UPDATE]**

Using pdb, I saw some outputs, data, contentType n filename is apparently setted up correct.

So, Where I went wrong?
Or what kind type is input of data?
*I ain't expert python programmer... like you see...* If someone used plone.api and upload pdf to plone, how you did it?

```
 36                             pdf_path,
 37                             filename=unicode(file_obj.id, 'utf-8'),
 38                     )
 39                     print('\n \n Criado: '+row['NDOPROCESSO']+'.')
 40                     transaction.commit()
 41
 42                     pdf_file.close()
 43  ->                 break
 44     csvfile.close()
 45
    (Pdb) file_obj.file.data
        'INMEQ/PastaGeral/PROCESSOINMEQ-AL.PDF'
    (Pdb) file_obj.file.contentType
        'application/pdf'
    (Pdb) file_obj.file.filename
        u'processoinmeq-al.pdf'
```

**[UPDATE 2]**

@Mathias, first thks, you're great!

My O.S. is:

```
jaf@ocs:~/plone4310/zinstance$ uname -a
Linux ocs 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u6 (2015-11-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Look my attempt:

```
jaf@ocs:~/plone4310/zinstance$ bin/instance -O a debug
Starting debugger (the name "app" is bound to the top-level Zope object)

>>> plone = app.a
>>> plone
<PloneSite at /a>
>>> from zope.component.hooks import setSite
>>> setSite(plone)
>>> from plone import api
>>> pdfpath = 'INMEQ/PastaGeral/PROCESSOINMEQ-AL.PDF' 
#I tried too with a full path, like you see in image print below
#'/home/jaf/plone4310/zinstance/INMEQ/PastaGeral/PROCESSOINMEQ-AL.PDF'
>>> pdfpath
'INMEQ/PastaGeral/PROCESSOINMEQ-AL.PDF'
>>> obj = api.content.create(type='File', title='a file', container=plone)
>>> obj
<ATFile at /a/a-file> #unique difference, between you and me, is ATFile not File.
>>> obj.id
'a-file'
>>> file_ = plone.get(obj.id)
>>> file_
<ATFile at /a/a-file>
>>> file_ = plone.get('a-file')
>>> file_
<ATFile at /a/a-file>
>>> from plone.namedfile.file import NamedFile
>>> pdf = open(pdfpath, 'r')
>>> pdf
<open file 'INMEQ/PastaGeral/PROCESSOINMEQ-AL.PDF', mode 'r' at 0x7f41b7b48030>
>>> file_.file = NamedFile(data=pdf, filename=unicode(obj.id, 'utf-8'), contentType='application/pdf')
>>> file_.file
<plone.namedfile.file.NamedFile object at 0x7f41b7b42500>
>>> import transaction
>>> transaction.commit()
>>> file_.file
<plone.namedfile.file.NamedFile object at 0x7f41b7b42500>
>>>
```

The local of files:
[image: Image Print]

And after transaction.commit(), we have it.

[image: Plone Site with empty File after commit.]

**[UPDATE 3 - AND WORKS]**

With the SUPER HELP of @Mathias, the script python for upload `File` Archetypes from txt and separation with semicolon.

```
from zope.site.hooks import setSite
from plone import api
import transaction
import csv
import os

local_path = '/path_to_plone_instace/plone4310/zinstance'
scan_path = 'path_with_txt_and_PDFs'
geral_path = 'folder_with_pdf_only'
txt_name = 'file_with_content.txt'
plone_site = 'plone_site'
plone_site_pasta = 'folder_upload_in_plone'

portal = app[plone_site]
setSite(portal)
container = portal[plone_site_pasta]

with open(os.path.join(local_path, scan_path, txt_name), 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
    for row in reader:
        pdf_id = str(row['PDF_ID'])
        pdf_file = open(os.path.join(local_path, scan_path, geral_path, str(pdf_id)), 'r')

        file_obj = api.content.create(
            container=container,
            type='File',
            title=str(row['PDF_TITLE']),
            description=str(row['PDF_DESCRIPTION']),
            safe_id=True,
            excludeFromNav=True
        )

        file_ = container.get(file_obj.id)

        file_.setFile(pdf_file)

        if int(file_obj.getFile().size()) <= 0:
            print str(file_obj.id) + ', Empty FILE!!! size: ' + str(file_obj.getFile().size())

        else:
            print str(file_obj.title) + ', success created, with size: ' + str(file_obj.getFile().size())

            transaction.commit()

csvfile.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following worked on a Plone 4.3.10 + plone.app.contenttypes (default DX types)

```
>>> plone = app.Plonedemo
>>> plone
<PloneSite at /Plonedemo>
>>> from zope.component.hooks import setSite
>>> setSite(plone)
>>> from plone import api
>>> pdfpath = '/Users/PATHTOPDF'

>>> obj = api.content.create(
...     type='File',
...     title='a file',
...     container=plone)
>>> file_ = plone.get('a-file')
>>> file_
<File at /Plonedemo/a-file>
```

I used NameFile instead of NamedBlobFile.. AFAIK both does the same.

```
>>> from plone.namedfile.file import NamedFile
```

**Looks like you need to deliver a file handler and not the actual content.**

```
>>> pdf = open(pdfpath, 'r')
>>> pdf
<open file '/Users/PATHTOPDF', mode 'r' at 0x10dca3150>
>>> file_.file = NamedFile(data=pdf, filename=u'bla.pdf', contentType='application/pdf')
>>> import transaction
>>> transaction.commit()
>>> file_.file
<plone.namedfile.file.NamedFile object at 0x10dca0230>
```

After booting the instance the file incl. PDF is there and works fine.

---

UPDATE: Example for Archetypes `File` content.

This must work now :-)

I assume you have a archetype File content
You can follow the same steps until adding the file to the content.

```
... 
>>> pdf = open(pdfpath, 'r')
>>> pdf
<open file '/Users/PATHTOPDF', mode 'r' at 0x10dca3150>
>>> file_.setFile(pdf)  # filehandler, NOT THE NAMEDFILE.
>>> obj.getFile().size()
155847
>>> import transaction
>>> transaction.commit()
```

This example is using the Archetypes default setter/getter.

Comment: arrrrrrghhhh... My file was there and I was able to download it! Can you do a `len(file_.file.data)` ? To make sure the file was in the debug console there! You may also check the `var/blobstorage` directory it should be there too.

Comment: The length of data is compatible with the imagem print above, in this case my output was `765814` when I call function len, as you say `len(file_.file.data)`. And about see what have in blobstorage i can't how do it, I tried [How Debug](http://docs.plone.org/manage/troubleshooting/transactions.html#how-to-debug-it) but don't work, and finally i do in linux `du -lhs var/blobstorage/`and my out is `44K     var/blobstorage/`. Thx again!

Comment: The disk usage of the storage ist 44K after commiting and NOT ending the debug session? Yes this could mean, that you have some issues with your storage and your does not make to the filesystem. Probably a stupid question but is your user (uses which is running zope) able to write in your blob directory?

Comment: In buildout we have `effective-user=jaf`, `buildout-user=jaf`and linux user is `jaf`, permissions in filesystem is `jaf:jaf`. I execute commands line in `bin/instance -O plone_site debug` (to exit command line I use `ctrl+d`) and `bin/instace run script.py` and the result are the same. I'll install Debia 8.5.0-amd64 and install Plone 4.3.10 again... and the Plone dependencies... and try again...  I thing could be something installed in OS...

Comment: I add a Archetypes example. I ran in the completely wring direction. I assumed you're using a Dexterity content type, but in Plone 4.3.10 Archetypes are still the default content types.

Comment: I am using the `File` type that comes standard in Plone, without installing Dexterity content type. And the Plone installation is standard too... only with `plone.api` and Plone dependecies in OS... like `build-essentilas`...

Comment: Well, then the Archetype approach I posted should work.

Comment: Thanks for you attention... I reinstall Debian, install all dependecies in README of Plone, and installed with user non-root, and execute the script again... same results... Looking for solution... Thx again, you was fantastic!

Comment: Well both solution I postet the one with Dexterity and the with Archetypes are working on my laptop and also on centOS machine. I don't know whats wrong in your case...

Comment: I didn't see your **UPDATE**, sorry... I tried with Example for Archetypes `File` content, and finally works. Mathias thank you very much... you are a great person...

Comment: I mislead you assuming it was Dexterity (The other content type framework). Great!! You may accept the answer, so others with the same issue can profit from this SO question and also know the solution works.

Comment: @JulianoAraújo We have something in common, I also appreciate Mathias' concrete help, constructive criticism and competent insights also a lot :-) Welcome to StackOverflow, please accept the answers solving your quests.

Answer (score 2):

PDF is a binary format so you might want to read on how to open files in Python. Something like `data=open(pdf_path, 'rb')` should help.

Also I recommend you learn about pdb and insert a breakpoint just before this line so you can inspect if everything works as expected.

Comment: I use `open(pdf_path, 'r').bytes()` :-)

Comment: @Mathias, I used a but this object hasn't attribute:

`    pdf_file = open(pdf_path, 'r').bytes()`
`    AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'bytes'`

Davi Lima, I tried 'rb', but, don't work... and I'm reade about open objects... I have few experience in Python... thx guys!